# Show Filters by Category

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, logic, e-commerce

Does anyone have any previous experience or ideas on how to proceed in the product filtering section by category on the e-commerce site?

Because the filter field in the left menu will vary according to the product category. The memory filter should appear in the phone category, but the body (S,M,L) filter should appear in the t-shirt category. The project was built in Laravel. Options and option values models are available. Should the option_id be added to the category table and set accordingly or manually?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what do you want to know ??

Comment: Example database structure or an idea. @AndriiSukhoi

Comment: _Side note:_ This question seems to be purely about database design, so neither PHP or Laravel is really relevant (the database structure should be based on the data, not on a framework or programming language).

Comment: question is very abstract, please edit it with some concrete example like: 
I hava products A,B,C, they are a stored in DB products table, which has next fields ... 
I want to reach ... and so on :)

Comment: Someone who understood what I meant answered. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can use pivot table for this purpose. If each category has its own filters and you have a filter table (you name it option here), you must create a pivot table like `category_option` to store `categoty_id` and `option_id`. This will help you when building filter menu in category page. Next use another table to store `product_id`, `option_id` and `value` for that option to store values for each individual product.

Comment: Big thanks Mohammad. I will try.